# Starting httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_procattr_perms_set_register

Tags: apache, centos, daemon, httpd.conf

I have upgraded apache httpd server from 2.4.6 to 2.4.46.
When I fire `systemctl start httpd` it shows the following error:

> Starting httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/httpd:
> undefined symbol: apr_procattr_perms_set_register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the apr apr-util package are missing or there was corruption during the installation of these packages. Could you please reinstall apr and apr util package and test.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your `apr` and `apr-util` versions are also updated on the server and that they reside in your shared libraries.

Try this to find what `httpd` has been compiled with and your current installed version.

```sh
httpd -V | grep 'APR '; rpm -q apr apr-util
```

You should then try and update either `apr` or `apr-util` accordingly.

```sh
yum update apr apr-util
```

Try again and if there is no change, update the machine fully, reboot and retry. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I got the similar error, by backend apache is stopped because of this error
**Error**: /usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/httpd: undefined symbol: apr_pescape_ldap

What I have done, to resolve above issue, JUST UPDATED THE apr(Apache Portable Runtime)

**yum update apr apr_pescape_ldap -y**

Resolved my issue.

Comment: Glad we could help